# Using a URL with AudioInputStream

Tags: java, url, audio, wav, clip

```
            URL url = new URL("http://www.dasolorfire.freehostia.com/sound/test.wav");
            AudioInputStream sound = AudioSystem.getAudioInputStream(url); //Sound.java:50
            DataLine.Info info = new DataLine.Info(Clip.class, sound.getFormat());
            clip = (Clip) AudioSystem.getLine(info);
            clip.open(sound);
            clip.addLineListener(new LineListener()
            {
                public void update(LineEvent event)
                {
                    if (event.getType() == LineEvent.Type.STOP)
                    {
                        event.getLine().close();
                    }
                }
            });
            clip.start();
```

This is my attempt at loading audio from a url. Not only is this very slow, but when I try to load the sound file I get this exception:

```
javax.sound.sampled.UnsupportedAudioFileException: could not get audio input stream from input URL
at javax.sound.sampled.AudioSystem.getAudioInputStream(Unknown Source)
at srcD.Sound.soundPlay(Sound.java:50)
```

My next attempt is replacing the url with an input stream.

```
            InputStream url = new URL("http://www.dasolorfire.freehostia.com/sound/test.wav").openStream();
            AudioInputStream sound = AudioSystem.getAudioInputStream(url);
```

The problem with this is that I get this error:

```
java.io.IOException: mark/reset not supported
at java.io.InputStream.reset(Unknown Source)
at java.io.FilterInputStream.reset(Unknown Source)
at sun.net.www.protocol.http.HttpURLConnection$HttpInputStream.reset(Unknown Source)
at com.sun.media.sound.SoftMidiAudioFileReader.getAudioInputStream(Unknown Source)
at javax.sound.sampled.AudioSystem.getAudioInputStream(Unknown Source)
at srcD.Sound.soundPlay(Sound.java:50)
```

(I am trying to load sound for a jnlp)

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The first error (could not get audio input stream from input URL) indicates that the format of the audio data you are referring to is not supported. I don't know if your example code uses a real URL, but if I try to invoke http://www.dasolorfire.freehostia.com/sound/test.wav, I am redirected to http://www.freehostia.com/ and get an HTML page, not the expected WAV file.

The second error (mark/reset not supported) should be self explanatory. The API documentation for [AudioSystem.getAudioInputStream(InputStream)](http://docs.oracle.com/javase/7/docs/api/javax/sound/sampled/AudioSystem.html#getAudioInputStream%28java.io.InputStream%29) explains why the provided InputStream must support the mark and reset features (these features are optional for specific InputStream implementations).

Comment: I just realized that with the first error. I don't know why. In the control panel, the file works fine. On the website, the file doesn't work. The other wav files work though.

Comment: Thanks for your answer! The main error was with the sound file not working on the website, which I fixed it by putting the sound file in the jar. I have one more question though, the 2 working files took a long time to load when ran from the internet. How can I speed it up?

Answer (score 3):

As far as the second error goes, you may be able to get this to work by wrapping the input stream in a BufferedInputStream like this:

```
        InputStream is = new URL("http://www.dasolorfire.freehostia.com/sound/test.wav").openStream();
        BufferedInputStream bis = new BufferedInputStream( is );
        AudioInputStream sound = AudioSystem.getAudioInputStream(bis);
```

Comment: i got this error mate : UnsupportedAudioFileException: could not get audio input stream from input stream

Comment: Sure, there's no file at that URL anymore.